# Reuse field values in WHERE clause

Tags: t-sql, where-clause, sql-server-2014

How do I optimize the performance of the following `T-SQL` so `heavyFunctionCall` function will get called just once.

Looking for the fastest option among table variables, temp tables, CTEsor something else?

SQL:

```
select dbo.heavyFunctionCall(a, b, c) 
from T 
where dbo.heavyFunctionCall(a, b, c) > 10
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at the query plan for the various options you describe?

Comment: I have not. My knowledge of TSQL is superficial. I thought that I can naturally use fields from select in where which isn't the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing this would only run your function once on every row instead of twice:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT dbo.heavyFunctionCall(a, b, c) AS x
  FROM T) a
WHERE x > 10
```

Answer (score 1):

```
declare proc tst (@x int)  -- set @x whatever you want.
                           -- the execution plan will be the same.
as 
begin
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT dbo.heavyFunctionCall(a, b, c) AS result
  FROM T) resultx
WHERE result > @x
end
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe this:

```
select hFC.result
from T 
cross apply ( select dbo.heavyFunctionCall(T.a, T.b, T.c) result ) hFC
where hFC.result > 10
```